# "Class path resource [config/game.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist" IntelliJ - Spring project not looking in correct directory?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, directory, filenotfoundexception

I'm making a Java Spring project in IntelliJ as an exercise and I don't understand a file configuration error I'm having.

Please look at my project directory layout as described in this screenshot:[image]

The three most important files here are the Main & GameConfig classes, and the game.properties file. Or, to use their full package directory names, `"console/src/main/java/academy.learnprogramming.console.Main"`, `"core/src/main/java/academy.learnprogramming.config.GameConfig"` and `core/src.resources.config.game.properties`

When I run project, the Main class tries to run the following code:

```
    package academy.learnprogramming.console;

    import academy.learnprogramming.MessageGenerator;
    import academy.learnprogramming.NumberGenerator;
    import academy.learnprogramming.config.GameConfig;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

    public class Main {

        private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(com.sun.tools.javac.Main.class);

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            log.info("Guess the number");
            //== create the context first ==
            ConfigurableApplicationContext context
            = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(GameConfig.class);
            // rest of code, which we never get to because of an error with the above line
```

When I try to create ConfigurableApplicationContext, I am trying to call the GameConfig class from the `Core` package. But I get this runtime error instead:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to parse configuration class
>   [academy.learnprogramming.config.GameConfig]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [config/game.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

I do not understand why it thinks GameConfig does not exist, or how to fix it. No solutions I have found seem to have the precise answer for this. I have gotten a configuration comparison from someone whose code is identical to mine, but neither of us understand why their version works and mine does not.

For comparison's sake, the `GameConfig` class has the following code:

```
    package academy.learnprogramming.config;

    import academy.learnprogramming.GuessCount;
    import academy.learnprogramming.MaxNumber;
    import academy.learnprogramming.MinNumber;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "academy.learnprogramming")
    @PropertySource("classpath:config/game.properties")
    public class GameConfig {
    //rest of GameConfig code here...
```

While game.properties is as simple as this:

```
    game.maxNumber = 100
    game.guessCount = 10
    game.minNumber = 0
```

I can't find a question similar to this, nor do other websites point out what's going on. Does anyone have any idea why this error might be happening? Any advice would be invaluable

Comment: Does it help if you place the whole 'resources' directory inside your sources root folder ('java')?

Comment: Does `console` module depend on the `core` module? Do you see `game.properties` file in the output/classpath when the project is built? [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help to investigate the issue.

Comment: @Koyasha I refactored it into the `core/src` directory, but unfortunately it didn't.
@CrazyCoder I apologise. I'm new to IntelliJ so I don't know how to check if there's this dependency or to read the output/classpath. I'm also unsure how this example is missing the MCV requirements

Comment: Please share a sample project to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I don't think I can attach a project file to my question. Do you mean as a downloadable URL?

Comment: Yes, use any file sharing service.

Comment: Had a similar issue today. Got it fixed by deleting the`.idea` folder and creating a new project. You could also move it somewhere else, and selectively copy back the configs that you want to have back.